# How to join input and select in one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-select2

E.g, I know about select2 javascript plugin, that lets to create select elements with handy filter option: 
[image]

In my project, I'd like to have the similar functionality, but instead of filtering option I need to add selected options and, if there are no coincidences, add a new entered (in input field) item to collection.

As I understood, this plugin creates a container with an HTML form:

```
createContainer: function () {
        var container = $(document.createElement("div")).attr({
            "class": "select2-container"
        }).html([
            "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='select2-choice' tabindex='-1'>",
            "   <span class='select2-chosen'>&#160;</span><abbr class='select2-search-choice-close'></abbr>",
            "   <span class='select2-arrow' role='presentation'><b role='presentation'></b></span>",
            "</a>",
            "<label for='' class='select2-offscreen'></label>",
            "<input class='select2-focusser select2-offscreen' type='text' aria-haspopup='true' role='button' />",
            "<div class='select2-drop select2-display-none'>",
            "   <div class='select2-search'>",
            "       <label for='' class='select2-offscreen'></label>",
            "       <input type='text' autocomplete='off' autocorrect='off' autocapitalize='off' spellcheck='false' class='select2-input' role='combobox' aria-expanded='true'",
            "       aria-autocomplete='list' />",
            "   </div>",
            "   <ul class='select2-results' role='listbox'>",
            "   </ul>",
            "</div>"].join(""));
        return container;
    },
```

What changes should I perform with this or any other plugin in order to gain what I'd like to have in my project? Are there any alternatives to this solution?

Comment: have no idea what you are asking for. Please explain expected UI in more detail. It actually sounds like functionality already available in select2

Comment: I've already solved this problem. This is what I was asking for: http://jsfiddle.net/7dktstde/1/